# How to force Linq to generate sql satements with exact with(nolock) statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using IsolationLevel ReadUncommited to create a with(nolock) SQL statement but linq does not generate nolock in SQL queries.

I need a way to generate with(nolock) on liq generated SQL statements.
My code is

```
    var transactionOptions = new System.Transactions.TransactionOptions();

    transactionOptions.IsolationLevel=
    System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted;

    using (var transactionScope = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope(
    System.Transactions.TransactionScopeOption.Required,
    transactionOptions)
    )
    {
        var x=from b in TBLAgents where b.AgentID!=2 select b;
        x.Dump();
        transactionScope.Complete();
    }
```

but it generates SQL query without block statement

```
-- Region Parameters
    DECLARE @p0 Int = 2
    -- EndRegion
    SELECT [t0].[AgentID], [t0].[ParentID], [t0].[AgentType], [t0].[AgentName], [to].        [AgentUsername], [t0].[AgentPassword], [t0].[CreateDate], [t0].[Status], [t0].[SecurityPublicKey], [t0].[SecurityPrivateKey], [t0].[OfflineProposalDetailInfo], [t0].[IsPlatformService], [t0].[PlatformServiceURL], [t0].[ServiceClassName], [t0].[PlatformServiceUserId], [t0].[PlatformServiceUserName], [t0].[PlatformServicePassword], [t0].[BranchId], [t0].[OfflineMailingDisabled], [t0].[WebApiKey], [t0].[AlternateId]
```

FROM [TBLAgent] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[AgentID] <> @p0

Comment: Why do you think you need to use NOLOCK? Are you aware of all the "fun" things using that type of isolation brings to the table? Things like missing and/or duplicate rows being returned? Bugs in the system that happen but are impossible to reproduce because the data access is unpredictable?

Comment: See also https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere and https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/10/using-nolock-heres-how-youll-get-the-wrong-query-results/ and https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/08/but-nolock-is-okay-when-the-data-isnt-changing-right/. In the vast majority of situations, either `SNAPSHOT` isolation, or a `TABLOCK` hint is the correct solution.

Comment: `NOLOCK` can cause not just missing or duplicate rows, but missing or duplicate *whole pages*, and may cause things like a join which is expected to be unique to be duplicated, blowing the whole query out of the water. It can also still cause blocking due to schema locks, and you can get weird errors, especially if you try using it in modification queries.

Comment: I need to force linq to send nolock statement to SQL using my linq queries but when we use IsolationLevel the nolock statement is not sent to sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A READ_UNCOMMITTED transaction and a NOLOCK hint are *alternative* mechanisms for requesting dirty reads.  NOLOCK has no effect if you're running in a READ_UNCOMMITTED transaction.